# Spark Cassandra Connector: for comprehension error (type mismatch)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

### Problem

Maybe this is due to my lack of Scala knowledge, but it seems like adding another level to the *for comprehension* should just work. If the first *for comprehension* line is commented out, the code works. I ultimately want a Set[Int] instead of '1 to 2', but it serves to show the problem. The first two lines of the *for* should not need a type specifier, but I include it to show that I've tried the obvious.

### Tools/Jars

- IntelliJ 2016.1
- Java 8
- Scala 2.10.5
- Cassandra 3.x
- spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar (pre-built)
- spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.6.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.jar (pre-built)
- spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.6.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.jar (I built)

### Code

```
case class NotifHist(intnotifhistid:Int, eventhistids:Seq[Int], yosemiteid:String, initiatorname:String)
case class NotifHistSingle(intnotifhistid:Int, inteventhistid:Int, dataCenter:String, initiatorname:String)

object SparkCassandraConnectorJoins {
  def joinQueryAfterMakingExpandedRdd(sc:SparkContext, orgNodeId:Int) {

  val notifHist:RDD[NotifHistSingle] = for {
    orgNodeId:Int <- 1 to 2   // comment out this line and it works
    notifHist:NotifHist <- sc.cassandraTable[NotifHist](keyspace, "notifhist").where("intorgnodeid = ?", orgNodeId)
    eventHistId <- notifHist.eventhistids
  } yield NotifHistSingle(notifHist.intnotifhistid, eventHistId, notifHist.yosemiteid, notifHist.initiatorname)
  ...etc...
 }
```

### Compilation Output

```
Information:3/29/16 8:52 AM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1s 507ms
       /home/jpowell/Projects/SparkCassandraConnector/src/com/mir3/spark/SparkCassandraConnectorJoins.scala
**Error:(88, 21) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Nothing]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[com.mir3.spark.NotifHistSingle]
      orgNodeId:Int <- 1 to 2
                    ^**
```

### Later

@slouc Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I was using the *for comprehension's* syntactic sugar to also keep state from the second statement to fill elements in the NotifHistSingle ctor, so I don't see how to get the equivalent map/flatmap to work. Therefore, I went with the following solution:

```
def joinQueryAfterMakingExpandedRdd(sc:SparkContext, orgNodeIds:Set[Int]) {

  def notifHistForOrg(orgNodeId:Int): RDD[NotifHistSingle] = {
    for {
      notifHist <- sc.cassandraTable[NotifHist](keyspace, "notifhist").where("intorgnodeid = ?", orgNodeId)
      eventHistId <- notifHist.eventhistids
    } yield NotifHistSingle(notifHist.intnotifhistid, eventHistId, notifHist.yosemiteid, notifHist.initiatorname)
  }
  val emptyTable:RDD[NotifHistSingle] = sc.emptyRDD[NotifHistSingle]
  val notifHistForAllOrgs:RDD[NotifHistSingle] = orgNodeIds.foldLeft(emptyTable)((accum, oid) => accum ++ notifHistForOrg(oid))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For comprehension is actually syntax sugar; what's really going on underneath is a series of chained `flatMap` calls, with a single `map` at the end which replaces `yield`. Scala compiler translates every for comprehension like this. If you use `if` conditions in your for comprehension, they are translated into filters, and if you don't yield anything `foreach` is used. For more information, see [here](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html#23.4).

So, to explain on your case - this:

```
val notifHist:RDD[NotifHistSingle] = for {
  orgNodeId:Int <- 1 to 2   // comment out this line and it works
  notifHist:NotifHist <- sc.cassandraTable[NotifHist](keyspace, "notifhist").where("intorgnodeid = ?", orgNodeId)
  eventHistId <- notifHist.eventhistids
} yield NotifHistSingle(...)
```

is actually translated by the compiler to this:

```
val notifHist:RDD[NotifHistSingle] = (1 to 2)
  .flatMap(x => sc.cassandraTable[NotifHist](keyspace, "notifhist").where("intorgnodeid = ?", x)
  .flatMap(x => x.eventhistids)
  .map(x => NotifHistSingle(...))
```

You are getting the error if you include the `1 to 2` line because that makes your for comprehension operate on a sequence (vector, to be more precise). So when invoking `flatMap()`, compiler expects you to follow up with a function that transforms each element of your vector to a [GenTraversableOnce](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce.html). If you take a closer look at the type of your for expression (most IDEs will display it just by hovering over it) you can see it for yourself:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

This is the problem. Compiler doesn't know how to `flatMap` the vector `1 to 10` using a function that returns `CassandraRDD`. It wants a function that returns `GenTraversableOnce`. If you remove the `1 to 2` line then you remove this restriction.

Bottom line - if you want to use a for comprehension and yield values out of it, you have to obey the type rules. It's impossible to flatten a sequence consisting of elements which are not sequences and cannot be turned into sequences.

You can always `map` instead of `flatMap` since map is less restrictive (it requires `A => B` instead of `A => GenTraversableOnce[B]`). This means that instead of getting all results in one giant sequence, you will get a sequence where each element is a group of results (one group for each query). You can also play around the types, trying to get a `GenTraversableOnce` from your query result (e.g. invoking `sc.cassandraTable().where().toArray` or something; I don't really work with Cassandra so I don't know).